# Cannot subscript a value of type 'inout [String]' (aka 'inout Array<String>') in bar graph

Tags: swift, int

There are same questions with same errors, but I couldn't find any answer same as mine. So, I am making a graph (chartData) that will be supplied by UIlabels from another view controller (score1, 2 & 3). The function that I am having problem with is the heightforBarViewAt. It Says: Cannot subscript a value of type 'inout [String]' (aka 'inout Array'). Please help me.

```
var chartData = [score1, score2, score3]
```

}

```
func barChartView(_ barChartView: JBBarChartView!, heightForBarViewAt index: UInt) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(chartData[Int(index)])
```

}